# Convolution of functionals on compact quantum group

Tags: c-star-algebras, quantum-groups, tensor-products, convolution

Let $\mathbb{G}= (A, \Delta)$ be a ($C^*$-algebraic) compact quantum group. In a paper I'm reading, the space $A^*= B(A, \mathbb{C})$ obtains a product
$$\omega_1*\omega_2:= (\omega_1\otimes \omega_2) \circ \Delta$$
and this is used to prove the existence of the Haar functional on a compact quantum group.

**Question:** How is $\omega_1 \otimes \omega_2$ defined here? Clearly we have a linear mapping $$\omega_1 \odot \omega_2: A \odot A \to \mathbb{C}$$
on the algebraic tensor product, but we need continuity to extend this to the completion $A \otimes A$ (with respect to the minimal $C^*$-norm on the algebraic tensor product $A \odot A$).

In general, I believe $\omega_1 \odot \omega_2$ must not be continuous, though this result does hold when one works with states on the $C^*$-algebra $A$.

Comment: Every bounded linear functional on a $C^\ast$-algebra is a linear combination of states, so $\omega_1\odot \omega_2$ extends to the spatial (minimal) tensor product for all $\omega_1,\omega_2 \in A^\ast$ by a theorem of Takesaki.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thanks a lot! That makes sense! If you want, you can make that an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every bounded linear functional on a $C^\ast$-algebra is a linear combination of states, so $\omega_1\odot \omega_2$ extends to the spatial (minimal) tensor product for all $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in A^\ast$ by a theorem of Takesaki.

Answer (score 3):

A result which I find a bit surprising is this.  Let $A,B$ be $C^*$-algebras. Then:

1. For $\omega_1\in A^\ast$ and $\omega_2\in B^\ast$, the functional $\omega_1\otimes\omega_2$ is also bounded as a map $A\otimes_{\max} B \rightarrow \mathbb C$;
2. This means that the algebraic tensor product $A^\ast\otimes B^\ast$ maps into the dual of $A\otimes_\beta B$ where $\beta$ is *any* $C^*$-tensor norm on $A\otimes B$;
3. The resulting norm (the map is injective) on $A^\ast\otimes B^\ast$ *is the same* for any norm $\beta$.

You can find this in Chapter IV, Proposition 4.10 of Takesaki's book, for example.